# How to make RaisedButton property 'onPressed' execute without user clicking the button. onPressed has asyc function

Tags: flutter

I am getting username and password when navigating to this page. AuthProvider has method to login that will get authToken from the server which is needed to go to the item_list page. All I need to do is to auto-click the button! Appreciate if someone can help!

```
  Widget _autoLogin() {
    return FlatButton(
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
      child: Text('auto logging...', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      onPressed: () async {
        var authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
        var loggedInUser = await authProvider.login(
            widget.savedUsername, widget.savedPassword);
        if (loggedInUser != null) {
          setState(() {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/item_list');
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making button auto-click you can extract your logic into function which you can pass it to button press as well as you can also call after getting  authToken from the server

Example:-

```
Widget _autoLogin() {
  return FlatButton(
    color: Colors.redAccent,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
    child: Text('auto logging...', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
    onPressed: autoLogin,
  );
}

autoLogin() async {
  var authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
  var loggedInUser = await authProvider.login(
      widget.savedUsername, widget.savedPassword);
  if (loggedInUser != null) {
    setState(() {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/item_list');
    });
  }
}
```

You can also move autoLogin function to provider and give it's reference from provider so you can call this function after getting authToken

Comment: Thanks Ankit! This will take me to the ItemList page, but ItemList page keeps loading infinitely... I have not figure out the exact reason for it. Instead of doing this, I used Future.delayed with Duration(millisecond: 500) in initState(), and it worked out..